# render_template() not working unable to update page with new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I am writing a web application using Flask.

**Server Code**

```
@app.route('/load')
def load(): 
    return render_template("next.html",message = {"date_to":"from","date_from":tmp,"error_stat":[30,400,21,45],"mac":[["1.1.1.1","1.2.1.2","3.2.1.1","3.1.4.5","1.3.2.4","5.5.4.3","2.1.6.7"],                                                  ["6.1.1.1","1.2.3.2","3.2.1.1","3.2.4.5","1.3.2.4","5.5.4.3","2.1.6.7"],                                                    ["9.1.1.1","4.2.1.2","3.2.1.1","3.7.4.5","1.3.2.4","5.5.4.3","2.1.6.7"],                                                    ["10.1.1.1","1.2.1.2","3.2.1.1","3.6.4.5","1.3.2.4","5.5.4.3","2.8.6.7"]],                                                  "ip":[["1.1.1.1","1.2.1.2","3.2.1.1","3.1.4.5"],                                                ["6.1.1.1","3.2.4.5","1.3.2.4","5.5.4.3","2.1.6.7"],                                                    ["9.1.1.1","4.2.1.2","3.2.1.1","3.7.4.5","1.3.2.4","5.5.4.3","2.1.6.7"],                                                    ["10.1.1.1","3.6.4.5","1.3.2.4","5.5.4.3","2.8.6.7"]]                                           })

@app.route('/submitdate',methods=['GET'])
def submitdate():
    tmp1 = request.form.get('start_date')
    tmp2 = request.form.get('end_date')
    return render_template("next.html",message ={"date_to":tmp2,"date_from":tmp1,"error_stat":[130,100,121,145],"mac":[["4.1.1.1","1.2.1.2","3.2.1.1","3.1.4.5","1.3.2.4","5.5.4.3","2.1.6.7"],                                                 ["5.1.1.1","1.2.3.2","3.2.1.1","3.2.4.5","1.3.2.4","5.5.4.3","2.1.6.7"],                                                    ["6.1.1.1","4.2.1.2","3.2.1.1","3.7.4.5","1.3.2.4","5.5.4.3","2.1.6.7"],                                                    ["7.1.1.1","1.2.1.2","3.2.1.1","3.6.4.5","1.3.2.4","5.5.4.3","2.8.6.7"]],                                                   "ip":[["8.1.1.1","1.2.1.2","3.2.1.1","3.1.4.5"],                                                    ["9.1.1.1","3.2.4.5","1.3.2.4","5.5.4.3","2.1.6.7"],                                                    ["0.1.1.1","4.2.1.2","3.2.1.1","3.7.4.5","1.3.2.4","5.5.4.3","2.1.6.7"],                                                    ["1.1.1.1","3.6.4.5","1.3.2.4","5.5.4.3","2.8.6.7"]]                                                    })
```

**JQuery Front End**

```
$('#buttonid').on('click', function (e) {
    $.get("/submitdate",{"start_date":$('#start').val(),"end_date":$('#end').val()},function(data,status)
    {              
            //location.reload(true);(Can I do this to reload the page with new data???)        

    }); 
});
```

I hae a button with id "`buttonid`", when I click it, it should send data to server using GET. Then, the page should be loaded with new data.In my HTML code, I am accessing the data from the server as `{{message.error_stat[0]}}`(For instance). I don't have any issue when I load the page for the first time. But when I click button to submit the data and get new data using GET, I am not able to update with new data. The syntax `{{message.error_stat[0]}}` is not working. May I know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
$('#buttonid').on('click', function (e) {
   window.location.href = '/submitdate?start_date='+$('#start').val()+'&end_date='+$('#end').val()
});
```

Then,

```
tmp1 = request.args.get('start_date')
tmp2 = request.args.get('end_date')
```

Comment: If you're going to trigger a new page load there's no need for JavaScript. You can allow the form to submit.